# Migrating from JS to TS, running into "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm working on moving a project from JavaScript to TypeScript, and am getting really tripped up on my Webpack, Babel, and now TypeScript configurations. After putting in a few hours to make the switch in one area of the project, running it produces a dreaded `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. [Here is the full repo](https://github.com/gusbmurphy/what-about-a-band-called/tree/typescript), but here are my various config files:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/", 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "strictNullChecks": true, 
    "module": "es6", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react", 
    "target": "es5", 
    "allowJs": true, 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "app"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        use: { loader: "ts-loader" },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "source-map-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    mongoose: "commonjs mongoose",
    // react: "React",
    // "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
};
```

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "what-about-a-band-called",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A way to share and rank band name ideas.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test-nyc": "nyc --include 'src' --exclude '**/*.spec.js' --exclude '**/*.spec.jsx' --exclude 'src/util/test-setup.js' --all mocha --require @babel/register --require './src/util/test-setup.js' './src/**/*.spec.js' './src/**/*.spec.jsx'",
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register --require './src/utility/test-setup.js' './src/**/*.spec.js' './src/**/*.spec.jsx' ",
    "start": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "initialize": "babel-node src/server/initialize-db",
    "server": "babel-node src/server/server",
    "server-test": "babel-node src/server/server.spec",
    "start-dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run dev\"",
    "load-dummy-data": "babel-node src/utility/load-dummy-db.ts",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Gus Murphy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...lots of these
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...and lots of these
  }
}
```

```
// .babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": {
                "node": "current"
            }
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Since I'm very new to TS, and relatively new to web development, I'm really getting lost in the sauce of what is supposed to be going on in these files, and they've unfortunately become a hodge-podge of various settings tutorials have told me to do, but not fully explained why. Does anything here immediately jump out at anybody as obviously wrong? The script I'm trying to execute currently that's giving me that error is `load-dummy-db.ts` using the command `npm run load-dummy-data`, but I'm not sure if that's really relevant, I'm hoping that I've included enough information with just the configurations. Please let me know if there's more relevant information I can share!

Comment: What import statement in what file is giving you that error?

Comment: @AlexWayne it's in `src/utility/load-dummy-db.ts`, the very first import: `import * as faker from "faker";`